# Make both discount Special Price + Catalog Price Rule

Tags: ce-1.8.1.0, discount

I setup Catalog Price rule as discount and it works well

but a product which have already special price can not be discount for my catalog price rule

the product just show the special price

How can I make Catalog Price rule also work as additional discount for product have special price?

e.g.) If original price is $100, special price $80, Catalog price rule is discount %10

I want to show $72 (as special price + catalog price rule)

currently the product show only special price $80

Answer (score 1):

Here is i have found solution after deep analysis.

you can override model

**app\code\core\Mage\CatalogRule\Model\Action\Index\Refresh.php**

i was in same situation before and here i have posted my answer with [my post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45595/catalog-price-rules-applied-to-special-price) you can use it for your needs.

i think it will sure help you.

Comment: Hesitate to edit core file first ... if there is no other answer I will try later this method Thank you for answer!

Comment: you have to make some custom extension for this. No need to change core files. you can see my detail answer which contents xml node how to override this