# How to force catalog price rule over default special price

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog-price-rules, price-rules, special-price

Currently in Magento CEv1.9, Minimum price is considered between default special price(entered from prices form for product) and price after discount applied through catalog price rule.
How can we force catalog price rule over default special price?
Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: This is not possible in default magento setup. You need to  customize for this requirement.

Comment: @MineshPatel: Can you give some pointers ?? so that I can start to implement it in correct way..

Comment: Check this answer http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45595/catalog-price-rules-applied-to-special-price

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer for your solution, but there is one way.

first **export all the products** using import export option and copy the excel sheet to your local system.

Than you can select all Products and update attributes and give "blank" under "special price" textfield and than save it.

Now Only "**Catalog Price rule**" will apply for products. In future if you want to give the speical prices , you can just import that excel sheet for only **sku** and **special price** columns

Comment: Thanks for your time.. But I can not use this way.. I must have special prices..