# magento set "catalog price rules" *only* if special price was not set

Tags: magento-1, catalog-price-rules, price-rules, rules

I am looking at magento "catalog price rules" and although I have added the special_price to filter conditions: I dont think I can do the following

**question**: 
How can I only apply the "catalog price rules" if the special_price was not already set

Aim: target only products that do not already have a special price set

[image]

http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/marketing/price-rules-catalog.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Please follow this image and add the condition as per the image. If you can not see the special price attribute in dropdown than navigating to the **admin >> Catalog >> Attributes >> Manage Attributes** and search '**special_price**' in attribute code input text box and edit this attribute.
And set 'Yes' to the 'Use for Promo Rule Conditions'.
After that Special price will be shown in that condition dropdown.

Comment: Thx. But how to filter on is not empty

Comment: I am not getting you.. can you please explain ?

Comment: How can we set it only if the special price is empty. So maybe data set.

Comment: My above solution will work on this condition. can you apply once and let me know the conclusion for the same.

Answer (score 0):

I read this

> Currently magento is using the special price if its lower than the applied catalog price rule.

here: [Catalog Price Rules applied to special_price](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45595/catalog-price-rules-applied-to-special-price)

Am I correct to assume in 1.9.3.3 this is still working as follow? 
- if special prics is lower than "catalog price rule" then the "catalog price rule" is used
- otherwise the special_price is applied